# "No jdk specified", while trying to install apk on a physical device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I was creating an android application and everything was working fine up until four days ago, when I tried to send an apk(the apk was signed)to my friend through the email. But the apk wasn't getting installed on my friend's phone, every time he used tried to install the apk through his laptop using android studios an error popped up saying that "no jdk specified for app-debug, error installing the app" and if he tried to install the app directly through on his mobile using the email then the error popped up saying "There was a problem parsing the error". But my app runs fine on my emulator and any device I install it on using usb debugging. But if I send the apk to any other phone then these two error pops up. I have already gone through a lot of stuff on stack overflow but nothing seemed to work below is my gradle config in case it helps.

Below is module level gradle.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc.tbd2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
            aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.Goodiebag:Pinview:v1.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0-rc02'

    //for material dialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'


    implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.7.2'
    //image compression
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jgabrielfreitas:BlurImageView:1.0.1'
    //twitter
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'

    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'




}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project Gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{url 'https://jitpack.io'}

        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Check if installation from unknown sources is enabled on installing device.

Comment: yes it is enabled I checked it but still no progress.